# PHP,MySQL - I validate file type upload, but it still insert to database. what's wrong with my code?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm doing php upload multiple files  and rename them.  So I use array input field name and use for loop to rename each file into date + ordinal number suffix.

I do validate the file type too, It can prevent upload other file-type to directory successfully. But it still insert filename to database. what's wrong with my code?

```
<form action="upload.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Username :
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            Image 1 :
                <input type="file" name="images[]" />
                <br>

            image 2 :
                <input type="file" name="images[]" />
</form>
```

in upload.php page

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
      $count=count($_FILES["images"]["name"]);

      $arr_newname = array();

    for($i=1; $i <= $count; $i++)
    {   
        if ((($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i-1] == "image/gif")
             || ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i-1]  == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["images"]["type"][$i-1]  == "image/png"))
            && ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i-1] < 2000000)) //2 MB
        {

             if ($_FILES["images"]["error"][$i-1]  > 0)
             {
                 echo "File Error : " . $_FILES["images"]["error"][$i]  . "<br />";
             }
             else 
             {


                if (file_exists("path/to/".$_FILES["images"]["name"][$i-1] ))
                {
                   echo "<b>".$_FILES["images"]["name"][$i-1]  . " already exists. </b>";
                }
                else
                {
                   $newname = date('Y-m-d')."_".$i.".jpg";
                   $arr_newname[$i-1] = $newname;
                   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$i-1] , "path/to/".$newname);

                   $data = array(
                     'username' => $_POST['username'],
                     'my_pic'.$i => $arr_newname[$i-1],
                   );
                   $this->db->insert('oav_album', $data);       
                 }
               }
             }
                else
                {
                   echo "Invalid file" ;
                   exit();
                } 
          }
       }
```

Comment: OK I fix it already

Comment: It's unclear, what is inserted into database? Here's only one insert query and what does it insert? Filename which is __what__?

Comment: @u_mulder it's just php framework insert style.  I insert the  $arr_newname[$i-1] to column mypic1 and mypic2.  arr_newname is the newname for image1 and image2  (loop)

Comment: Nevermind, paranthesis are correct.

Comment: I don't understand __what__ is inserted? __Why__ is it should not be inserted?